# flickering issue in mozilla while using firebug

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gwt, mozilla

i have developed one application using Google web toolkit with bootstrap CSS i am facing                some issue in

> Mozilla firebug.whenever i am using firebug the screen gets flickering can anybody help to
>   solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can be a bug due to compatibility issues. Try updating your browser/firebug to latest version.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by flickers? when does it flicker?

Comment: if it flickers when you move your mouse through the firebug window, it is normal behavior(assuming my perception of flicker). It highlights the background HTML Elements in question when you hover over the firebug window